# How do I write a simple c# script / app or software to block incoming udp packet?

Tags: c#, udp, firewall

I don't know if this can be done with a c# app. Can anyone point me to the direction of
Writing a app to :

- Check if packet is coming in to udp port : 1234
- And if packet comes from remote of port 1234 accept it, else reject
  it if comes from any other port.
- Also I would like to limit the amount of packet coming in at a rate
  say 32kb/s .

Is there a software, firewall of any kind that can do it? If not is there any windows library which can be used and script with c# app?

Comment: You would not generally write a c# program to do this. Use the operating system's packet filtering capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of documentations around. The `.NET Framework` has a [UdpClient class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx) You can also have a look to this [nice introduction to sockets.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/socketsincsharp.aspx)

As said [Andrew Barber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber), doing your own program for everyday use might not be the best solution. However, if you just want to play around with the TCP/IP stack you can also have a look at Python which provide great libraries to manage packets.